# Bluetooth option not working

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

bluetooth adapter is not working in ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Can anyone please help here

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: conencting bluetooth headset

Comment: Did you perform a Web search of your problem? What did you find?

Comment: The message says turned off what did you hope to get when you tried to attach the Bluetooth headset to Bluetooth that is turned off?

Comment: I'm not sure if OP got this figured out, but by looking at the screenshot, the "toggle" at the top indicates that the bluetooth is turned "on" yet the message says it's "turned off".  That appears to be a legitimate issue to me.  I know there's some commands the OP can run to get an idea of what could be wrong I just don't have them off hand.